# any means of returning bool for yaml variables in yaml-cpp?

Tags: c++, yaml, yaml-cpp

I have a config file for disabling specific code paths. I just added a bool option to the yaml file, and am having a hard time figuring out how yaml-cpp handles those. The documentation is a bit lighter than preferred, and I don't see anything for a `Node` that fits my use case. I could manually parse for the strings returned as `true` and `false`, but that seems like something the framework should support, as there are multiple styles of writing `true`and `false` in the spec. Is there any means of getting a bool value out of yaml-cpp?

`IsScalar`was the closest I could find.

```
void LoadConfig(string file)
{
   Node config = LoadFile(file);
   string targetDirectory;
   bool compile;
   if (config["TargetDirectory"])
      targetDirectory = config["TargetDirectory"].Scalar();
   if (config["Compile"])
      compile = Config["Compile"].IsScalar(); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You want the template `as()` method:

```
config["Compile"].as<bool>()
```

Or a neater way to do it all in one line instead of three using a default value (which also addresses your potential uninitialized variable bug):

```
bool compile = config["Compile"].as<bool>(false);
```